# Not detecting $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] on production (nginx php-fpm) server

Tags: php, nginx, pjax

Locally $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']; exists, but on production it does not exist.

I detect if the request was pjax and add some special logic in the case it is true.

```
$isPjax = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] === 'true';
```

On the left is local (php 7.4 apache), the right is production (php fpm 7.3.26). Both loaded the pages via pjax.
[image]

I assume I have to configure nginx to enable HTTP_X_PJAX to be available in the header. I googled around and nothing stuck out to me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your image is showing pjax on the right and left.  Could you clarify more?

Comment: @MattJamison HTTP_X_PJAX is not showing up in the request headers on the production server. $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']

Comment: The production server may be configured to hide *HTTP_ values. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#89567

Answer (score 1):

It usually does not exist if you are using PHP-FPM (CLI) in your Prod. It basically depends upon the nature of the application.